# Secure way to store pending user's password in Meteor

Tags: meteor, passwords

For my Meteor application, I would like to have the following signup process:

1. User registers username, email and **password**. *(He's not able to log in yet.)*
2. Confirmation email sent [`Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail`]
3. User confirms email [`Accounts.onEnrollmentLink`]
4. User is created. [`Accounts.createUser`] *(He's able to log in.)*

In order to achieve this, I feel like I would have to store the *plain text* password in a table of temporary users (step 1) in order to create the actual user later (step 3). Obviously this is a horrible idea.

I could of course only ask for the password as of step 3 and create the user at once - but it's not the behavior I would like to achieve.

So: Is there a proper way to store the password securely to later pass it to the user creation? Or is there a way to create a not-loginable users?

Comment: Is there a middle ground - like allow the user to login but automatically redirect them to a "you need to verify your email" route if he/she doesn't have any verified emails?

Comment: You could just store the hashed password the same way as you would when the user is created and store that in the temporary user table.

Comment: Agree with David, the common pattern is to allow login but disable actions.   Then again, salting & hashing is a great exercise every web dev should tackle!

Comment: BTW, is it just that you don't want the user to be in the users collection until after they confirm the email? You could let meteor accounts work as usual and simply set up a cron job to delete users without confirmation after X hours/days.

Comment: Correct me if I'm mistaken but I guess that I would lose a lot of the magic behind  `Accounts.createUser` [e.g. I and other packages rely on `Accounts.onCreateUser`] if I manually insert into the DB (which I guess is the only way if the password is already hashed/bcrypted).

Comment: I see what you mean. You can hash the password (accounts-password uses sha256) store it in your temp table and bypass the server hashing the password during the regular user creation if you give it an object like `{algorithm: "sha-256", digest: "yourhash"}`, check the [getPasswordString](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js#L32) and [createUser](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js#L686) functions.

Comment: @user3557327 - could you please add that as an answer? I'll stick with Jey DWork's answer because it's the most meteor-y and still provides the functionality I was looking for; but your approach is closest to the question and might be very helpful for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much you have to do yourself as Meteor brings everything you need for save password storage when you create a user with the built in methods. So you should use these methods from the beginning (Your step 1: `Accounts.createUser`, step 2: `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail`, step 3: `Accounts.verifyEmail`, step 4 isn't necessary anymore).

Now to get where you want to be you can use an approach like David Weldon suggested but use `Accounts.validateLoginAttempt` on the sever side. That is a little easier and the login isn't allowed in the first place.

For example you could have this code server side:

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function(loginAttempt){
    if (!loginAttempt.allowed) {
        // Only tell the user that something went wrong but not what to enhance security
        throw new Meteor.Error(901, 'Your login credentials are wrong. Try again.');
    } else {

        // In some cases this method isn't invoked with a correct user object...
        if (!loginAttempt.user) {
            throw new Meteor.Error(902, 'No valid user object. Make sure to validate your email address first.');
        }

        // If email verification is required check if the user has a valid email address and don't allow the login if he has none
        if (!loginAttempt.user.emails[0].verified) {
            throw new Meteor.Error(902, 'Your email address has to be verified first.');
        }

        // We have a correct login!
        return true;
    }
});
```

And now on the client side you can use a logic like this for the login

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function(callback) {
    if (callback === undefined) { 
        // Your login logic
    } else if (callback.error == 902) {
        // Your "not verfied" logic
    } else {
        // Your other login errors logic
    }
}
```

Note that you may have to adjust the registration process a little bit, too, as Meteor per default tries to login users directly after registration but this will not be possible anymore.
Also note that you may use `Accounts.validateLoginAttempt` for more than just that. For example you also could implement a logic here to only allow a certain amount of bad login attempts from the same IP.

Answer (score 1):

We've used a slightly different pattern in our app based on the accounts package

1. User registers
2. User is logged in normally

Out main site template conditions content with

```
<template name="main">
  {{#if currentUser}}
    {{#if verified }}
      ...
    {{else}}
      Notice to user to look for their verification email
    {{/if}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Based on a helper function

```
 Template.main.helpers({
   verified: function() { return Meteor.user().emails[0].verified; }
 });
```

This meets the requirement that the user can't do much if anything until they have been verified yet uses the accounts package in a simple and secure way.

I could see taking a related approach using iron:router as well.

Comment: I like this approach, but it unfortunately doesn't prevent the user from calling methods or read subscribe to collections from commandline. It would thus be necessary to add a lot of logic to all the methods/subscriptions/...

Comment: Here's a somewhat hacky approach - use the normal flow but when they register, on the server side rename the user.services.password.bcrypt key to user.services.password.pending (then log them out) and then swap it back post email-verification.

Comment: As a result of this question I've gone in to our app and added 3 simple, identical deny rules to every collection to prevent unverified users from doing any writes. In my case the subscriptions were already highly restricted for pending users.